# What is the best way to make private route in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made a private route in my app basically all the route in my app is private. So to make Private route I added a state `isAuthenticated` which is false by default but when user login in it becomes true. So on this `isAuthenticated` state I implemented a condition in private route component. But the problem with this is when user is logged in and refresh the page. I get redirect to `/` home page. I don't want that.

I am use token authentication here.

Here is my PrivateRoute.js

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

const PrivateRoute = ({ isAuthenticated, component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={(props) =>
      isAuthenticated ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/" />
    }
  />
);

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    isAuthenticated: state.user.isAuthenticated,
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute);
```

Comment: Store the `token` in the localStorage for persistence after the user has logged in  and check the token exists in that localStorage or not. If not, log the user out. If yes, let user enter to your `private route`

Comment: is it okay if i use both is authenticated and token ?

Comment: It is better if you update `isAuthenticated` from the localStorage token. Since that would the source of truth. There should an action that sets `isAuthenticated` to true upon having the token from the localStorage so that all of your components inside your App knows that user is authenticated.

Answer (score 1):

If all your routes when authenticated are private you can also just skip the autentication by route and use following

```js
import PrivateApp from './PrivateApp'
import PublicApp from './PublicApp'


function App() {
   // set isAuthenticated dynamically
   const isAuthenticated = true

   return isAuthenticated ? <PrivateApp /> : <PublicApp />
}
```

That way you do not need to think for each route if it is authenticated or not and can just define it once and depending on that it will render your private or public app. Within those apps you can then use the router normally and do not need to think who can access which route.

Answer (score 1):

If you validate the token against a server (which you should) then it's an asynchronous operation and `isAuthenticated` will be falsy initially, causing the redirect on refresh.

You one way around this is an `isAuthenticating` state, e.g.

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

const PrivateRoute = ({ isAuthenticated, isAuthenticating, component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={(props) => {
      if( isAuthenticating ){ return <Spinner /> }
      return isAuthenticated ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/" />
      }
    }
  />
);

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    isAuthenticated: state.user.isAuthenticated,
    isAuthenticating: state.authentication.inProgress
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute);
```

`isAuthenticating` should be `true` by default then set to `false` when the server response is received and the `user.isAuthenticated` state is known.